# Who first proved Fubini's theorem $n$th order integrals?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, calculus

Who first proved a generalized [Fubini theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fubini_theorem) for integrals of order $≥3$?

An $n$<sup>th</sup> order integral is $$\underbrace{\underset{x_n}\int\underset{x_{n-1}}\int\ldots\underset{x_1}\int}_{n} f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)dx_1dx_2\ldots dx_n.$$

By "a generalized [Fubini theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fubini_theorem)," I mean that all permutations of the  $x_i$ produce valid and equivalent integrals.

Comment: Can you clarify your sense of "order $\ge$ 3"?

Comment: @paulgarrett See what I added.

Comment: Odd -- I would have thought that any proof for order 2 would suffice to prove for order N.  Just break into a double-integral inside or outside of the remaining integrals.  We may need some commentary from math.SE here

Comment: It is a trivial consequence of order 2 and induction. You can get any permutation by transposing pairs.

Comment: @Conifold There was no commentary on math.SE on this question ([as you can see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385741/who-first-proved-a-generalized-fubini-theorem-for-integrals-of-order-%e2%89%a53#comment6968442_3385741)). Anway, an inductive argument should be sufficient.